# Disconnect vpn from Linux server

Tags: linux, vpn

I have pptpd for PPTP and openswan for L2TP installed on a Ubuntu server, which work without any problem. When a client connects to the server, a new connection is created shown as pppx in the `ifconfig` output, where x is an incremental number starting from 0. Now my question is, on the server side, is there a way to gracefully disconnect the vpn connection. I tried `ifdown ppp0`, but it doesn't work. It says:

```
# ifdown ppp0
ifdown: interface ppp0 not configured
```

So, is there any command that will disconnect the `ppp0` from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got the answer to this question:

```
kill -TERM `cat /var/run/ppp0.pid`
```